# Adding a FormActivate event in VB 6.0

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am used to C# and VS2010 :) but now have to modify some old VB 6.0 code.
How do we add an event in VB 6.0 IDE ?  like this?  This didn't get into my break point.

```
private sub form_activate()
 Call SomeControl.SetFocus
end sub
```

Also what is the LAST event that gets loaded when we are opening the main form on the application for the first time? Is it form_Activate or we also have a formShown event in VB 6.0 too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the VB6 form codeview window, in the uper left combobox select Form. Then the upper right combo box will show all the form's events and create them for you when selected. (unless they are highlighted which mean they already exist) I would first delete the code snippet you added to avoid confusion. The editor will wire up the event for you.

take a look at this for the sequence

http://visualbasic.about.com/library/faq/bleventseqa.htm

Comment: One minor point about the link: GotFocus only fires on a form that has no controls on it.  Try copying and pasting the code given in the link, run with a blank form, and then put a control on the form and run it again.  You'll see that the GotFocus event doesn't fire.    It gets more complicated, too.  Try putting

Comment: It gets more complicated, too.  Try putting 'Print "Hello World"' in the Activate event, with no controls.  Now, it goes Initialize, Load, Resize, Paint, Activate, GotFocus.  Presumably because it has to do a paint before doing the print.